# Why are double-quotes urlencoded as %22?

Tags: html, encode, urlencode

As far as I know, URL encoding exists because URLs only support ASCII encoding. But since `"` is already in the ASCII table, why should it be encoded as `%22` in URL encoding?

Comment: URL-encoding exists to encode any characters that cannot be represented in the URL ***under the restrictions imposed on the various URL components.*** E.g., `?` and `&` are *special characters* in the query component and cannot be included literally as is. It's not just about ASCII.

Comment: Also https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"` character falls under section 2.2 (URL Character Encoding Issues) of [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)  (Uniform Resource Locators), under [the "Unsafe" section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#page-3). The reason for the inclusion is:

> The quote mark (`"""`) is used to delimit URLs in some systems.

One case of this that I can think of is an HTML attribute. For example, if you have an `<a>` tag with an `href` attribute, you will likely enclose the URL between double quotes. If the `"` character is not quoted, then the tag becomes invalid:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/this"should-be-quoted">...</a>
```

The RFC also proceeds to say:

> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL.

---

Some examples of other unsafe characters:

> The characters `"<"` and `">"` are unsafe because they are used as the delimiters around URLs in free text.
>
> The character `"%"` is unsafe because it is used for encodings of other characters.
>
> The character `"#"` is unsafe and should always be encoded because it is used in World Wide Web and in other systems to delimit a URL from a fragment/anchor identifier that might follow it.

Answer (score 2):

> URLs only support ASCII encoding

That's not true. URL's don't support spaces or `/` or `&` or `?` for example even though they are valid ASCII characters because they have special meaning in URLs.

Valid characters in URLs are:

- A-Z
- a-z
- 0-9
- -
- _
- .
- ~

Other characters are not supported. Some, such as spaces and tabs are not supported because they have special meaning in protocols that usually use URLs such as HTTP. Others such as `?` and `&` are not supported because they have special meaning in URL syntax.